# web2py: cannot marshal class 'gluon.dal.Reference' objects

Tags: xml-rpc, web2py

I'm using web2py v1.98.2. with xml-rpc service. In the service.py controller I have:

```
@service.xmlrpc
def save_account(acct): 
    id = db.account.insert(code=acct['code'], name=acct['name'], 
                                             parent_id=acct['parent_id'])
    acct['id'] = id
    return dict(save_account=acct)
```

where account table is self-referencing table. This code throws "cannot marshal class 'gluon.dal.Reference' objects" error. After some test I found that it is related to id.
I thought id is integer, but documentation tells that it is an object. Then how can I convert it to integer? I want auto-incremented id back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this was simple. id object had **_*int*_**() method.